# connecting stringtemplate4 - antlr4 - java tesrig

Tags: java, antlr4, stringtemplate-4

I am new in antlr.

Translating code using ST through antlr v3 is good taste. I also see Jason2xml translation in parr book, but still confuse. How do i use or connecting ST-4 in antlr or java-test rig. Any tutorial or example like antlr-ST v3 ??

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR 4 does not have any syntactic sugar for working with StringTemplate. You can use its automatically generated listener and visitor interfaces to write classes that construct your templates manually.